# R multinomial logistic regression models assign penalties to avoid misclassification

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial, nnet

I am relatevly new to R and was wondering if function multinom from nnet package for fitting a logistic regression model enable the assignment of weight/penalties in order to tell the model to avoid mis-classification for a certain class. I have three classes that differ greatly in their distribution causing the dataset to be greatly unbalanced. That's why I thought weights/penalties can force the model to be more accurate in the class with less prevalence. This is the call:

```
 mnm <- multinom(formula = cut.rank ~ ., data = training.logist, trace = FALSE, maxit = 1000, weights=c(10,5,1))
```